# Scala Map a list of items to a value

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a list of *bigrams* of a sentence and another original list of *relevantbigrams*, I want to check that if any of the *relevantbigrams* are present in the sentences then I want to return the sentence. I was thinking of implementing it as follows: map each of the bigrams in the list to the sentence they come from then do a search on the key an return the value.

example:

```
relevantbigrams = (This is, is not, not what)
bigrams List(list(This of, of no, no the),list(not what, what is))
```

So each list is a bigram of separate sentences. Here "not what" from the second sentence matches, so I would like to return the second sentence. I am planning to have a map of Map("This of" -> "This of no the", "of no" ->"This of no the", "not what"->"not what is"). etc. and return the sentences that match on relevant bigram, so here I return "not what is"

This is my code:

```
val bigram = usableTweets.map(x =>Tokenize(x).sliding(2).flatMap{case Vector(x,y) => List(x+" "+y)}.map(z => z, x))
for(i<- 0 to relevantbigram.length)
    if(bigram.contains(relevantbigram(i)))) bigram.get(relevantbigram(i))
    else useableTweets.head
```

Comment: All the collection classes have `forall` and `exists` HOFs with take a predicate, apply it to elements of the collection and return `true` if that predicate is true of all (`forall`) or any (`exists`) of the elements of the collection. It sounds like that could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the order or `flatMap` and `map` the wrong way around:

```
val bigramMap = usableTweets.flatMap { x => 
    x.split(" ").sliding(2).
      map(bg => bg.mkString(" ") -> x)
} toMap
```

Then you can do your search like this:

```
relevantbigrams collect { rb if theMap contains rb => bigramMap(rb) }
```

Or

```
val found = 
  for { 
    rb <- relevantbigrams
    sentence <- theMap get rb
  } yield sentence
```

Both should give you a list, but from your code it appears you want to default to the first sentence if your search found nothing:

```
found.headOption.getOrElse(usableTweets.head)
```